# Converting Firestore Timestamp to JSON (Newtonsoft) returns empty object

Tags: c#, json, google-cloud-firestore, json.net, timestamp

I am reading data from a Firestore database and converting it to JSON using Newtonsoft in a C# Web API. However, the timestamp fields always convert to an empty object.

```
  ds is a DocumentSnapshot
  Dictionary<string, object> d = ds.ToDictionary();
  JToken jt = JToken.FromObject(d);
```

The above returns an empty object for the "date" field, which is a Firestore Timestamp:

```
date: {}
```

I have done the following as a workaround:

```
  var dt  = d.GetValueOrDefault("date");
  if (dt != null)
  {
    var dts = dt.ToString().Remove(0, 11);
    d["date"] = dts;
  }
```

I have tried the various date options for the conversion but none of them do anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type [`Google.Cloud.Firestore.Timestamp`](https://cloud.google.com/dotnet/docs/reference/Google.Cloud.Firestore/latest/Google.Cloud.Firestore.Timestamp) has no public properties, which is why it is serialized as an empty object `{}`.  To serialize it as a RFC 3339 UTC Timestamp string you will need to create a [custom `JsonConverter<Timestamp>`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/CustomJsonConverterGeneric.htm):

```
public class TimestampConverter : JsonConverter<Google.Cloud.Firestore.Timestamp> // namespace added for clarity
{
    //https://cloud.google.com/dotnet/docs/reference/Google.Cloud.Firestore/latest/Google.Cloud.Firestore.Timestamp
    public override Timestamp ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, Timestamp existingValue, bool hasExistingValue, JsonSerializer serializer) =>
        Timestamp.FromDateTime(serializer.Deserialize<DateTime>(reader).ToUniversalTime());

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, Timestamp value, JsonSerializer serializer) =>
        writer.WriteRawValue(JsonConvert.ToString(value.ToDateTime(), DateFormatHandling.IsoDateFormat, DateTimeZoneHandling.Utc));
}
```

Alternatively, if you need the generated JSON Timestamp values to adhere *precisely* to Google's expected RFC 3339 format, you may use [`Google.Apis.Json.RFC3339DateTimeConverter`](https://cloud.google.com/dotnet/docs/reference/Google.Apis/latest/Google.Apis.Json.RFC3339DateTimeConverter) to format the values:

```
public class TimestampConverter : JsonConverter<Google.Cloud.Firestore.Timestamp> // namespace added for clarity
{
    //https://cloud.google.com/dotnet/docs/reference/Google.Apis/latest/Google.Apis.Json.RFC3339DateTimeConverter
    //A JSON converter which honers RFC 3339 and the serialized date is accepted by Google services.
    static readonly Google.Apis.Json.RFC3339DateTimeConverter googleDateTimeConverter = new();
    
    //https://cloud.google.com/dotnet/docs/reference/Google.Cloud.Firestore/latest/Google.Cloud.Firestore.Timestamp
    public override Timestamp ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, Timestamp existingValue, bool hasExistingValue, JsonSerializer serializer) =>
        Timestamp.FromDateTime(serializer.Deserialize<DateTime>(reader).ToUniversalTime());

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, Timestamp value, JsonSerializer serializer) =>
        googleDateTimeConverter.WriteJson(writer, value.ToDateTime(), serializer);
}
```

Either way, to serialize to `JToken` using the following settings:

```
var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
{
    Converters = { new TimestampConverter() },
};
var jt = JToken.FromObject(d, JsonSerializer.Create(settings));
```

Or to a JSON string as follows:

```
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(d, settings);
```

The resulting JSON for your dictionary `d` will look like:

```json
{"date":"2023-04-11T21:01:01.110101Z"}
```

For the first converter, or

```json
{"date":"2023-04-11T21:08:01.110Z"}
```

For the second.  (The difference seems only to be in the precision.)

Demo fiddles [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/bGl9TE) and [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/t8t7ts).